# Using Regex .sub() lambda function removes spaces

Tags: python, regex, lambda, substitution

```
import re
from num2words import num2words

data = '[120:875 124:456] well 3 percent of 10000 USD is enough'
```

The numbers inside the brackets are time stamps. I'm trying to apply num2words to all other numbers (3, 1000). Unfortunately the space before and after the digit gets removed.

```
regex = r'\s+\d+\s'
x = re.sub(regex, lambda m: num2words(m.group()), data)
print(x)
-->[120:875 124:456] wellthreepercent often thousandUSD is enough
```

I tried to add spaces but when I do `' ' +` in front of the lambda function but I get a syntax error. For adding a space after the digit it seems to work though.

```
x = re.sub(regex, lambda m: num2words(m.group()) + ' ', data)
print(x)
---> [120:875 124:456] wellthree percent often thousand USD is enough
```

Comment: `regex = r'(?<=\s)\d+(?=\s)'` or `regex = r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)'` will do.

Comment: What is `<` doing? Haven't seen that in regex yet and couldn't find something about it

Comment: It is a lookbehind.